# Passing image to another app for editing/annotate from my App

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to allow my users to edit an image through any annotation app installed in their devices.
For this, I am sending image from my Application to another app for editing and retrieving it back.
I am using the following code in Xamarin.Android -

```
                var imgIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionEdit);

                var imgItem = (File)ImageAdapter.GetItem (p0.ItemId);
                var imgFileName = imgItem.Name;
                AndroidController.Current.SetImgFileName(Activity, imgFileName);
                imgIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraStream,
                    Uri.FromFile (imgItem));
                imgIntent.SetType ("image/*");

                if (Utils.CheckIntentAvailable (Activity, imgIntent)) {
                    StartActivity (imgIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity.ApplicationContext, "xyz", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
```

When I select "Skitch", the image is perfectly getting transferred to skitch, and getting back into my app once they share it with my app.

But, When I select "Inkboard" for the same purpose, the Inkboard app Intent triggers, but it doesn't pick the image I sent in Intent Extras.

Can anybody figure out what is happening here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try k3b's method in the answer below, send a uri directly instead of stream. But if the "Inkboard" app cannot pick your passed image and in the meanwhile other apps can, why you think it's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

note: i donot know anythink about xamarin

according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT the uri to be edited should go into `Intent.data`.

your code uses Intent.ExtraStream instead which is not standard.

I use this java code to to edit a jpg

```
    final Intent imgIntent = new Intent()
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
            // .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // #64 edit allow to modify file
    imgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);

                }
    File file = new File("/sd/path/to/image.jpg");
    final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    imgIntent.setData(uri);
    // imgIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

    startActivity (imgIntent);
```

note: if you use

```
    startActivityForResult(imgIntent);
```

your app get notified, when edit has finished or was canceld via `onActivityResult(...)`